# compute the minimum spanning tree of undirected graph

Tags: graph, minimum-spanning-tree

Consider an undirected graph with n vertices, and m edges. Assume that the edges are of two types: m1 red edges and m2 green edges. Thus m = m1 + m2. The red edges have weight 1, and the green edges have weight 2. Design and analyze an efficient algorithm to compute the minimum spanning tree of such a graph

Comment: You could at least have put your homework question in your own words. Show us your attempt at solving this, and tell us where you're having difficulty, and you'll get help.

Comment: Am actually confused in this problem ... i thought of solving it through the kruskals  algorithm but  not sure whether we should take both the edges or the minimum weight edge (1) or the  maximum weight edge (2)

Comment: According to the standard definition, the minimum spanning tree is the tree which spans all vertices and that has the minimum total weight for all the edges traversed.

Comment: so i believe i can do the kruskals algorithm by taking the red edges m1 of weight 1 alone to compute the minimum spanning tree

Comment: The red edges might not span the tree. Also, even if a spanning tree might be possible using only red edges, it might not have the least weight.

Comment: Am clearly not getting how to go about with this Really appreciate your time and help

Comment: It looks like Prim's algorithm would work. Choose any starting vertex, and repeatedly add any red edge that's not already in the MST from any node that _is_ in the MST. If there is no such red edge, add any such green edge, and continue. You're done when there are no more vertices to add, which always happens after adding n-1 edges.

Comment: Thanks and it really helps!

Comment: Oh, and I was wrong when I said that the MST containing only red edges might not have the least weight. I was thinking of a different kind of tree.

Comment: I would try a proof by induction. Remember # of edges in MST is (n-1).

Answer (score 0):

Arbitrarily pick a node in the undirected graph to begin with.

Create a hashtable with a key for every node in the graph. For the values of each node in the hastable, initialize the value to be -1 except for the node that you are beginning with, in which you initialize it to -100. These values will represent the cost to get to that node. "Special numbers" are -1 which signifies that the cost to get to that node is currently unknown and -100 which signifies that the node is already in the MST.

Now for each of the adjacent nodes to the node that you started with, update those nodes in the hashtable to be either 1 or 2 (depending on whether the edge between them is red or green).

Now look through the hashtable and determine which node has the lowest value that is not -1 or -100. If there are multiple ones with the same lowest cost, just randomly pick one of them. Add that node to the MST and set the value of that node to -100.

Update the hashtable with the newly included node included in the tree. It could be possible that a node was initially a cost of 2 away but is now a cost of 1 away with the added node. In that case, update the cost of those nodes from 2 to 1.

Keep repeating the above steps until all nodes have been covered. You now have your Minimum Spanning Tree!